# Constantly changing xls files on Samba server

Tags: samba, smb

Something that I saw in the past before, and now again when doing a diff of a complete samba share and the backup of the night before, I saw that xls files seems to change at random events. A lot of them are files that people haven't used in a long time, and they have similar changes.

Compare these hexdumps:

[image]

[image]

Sometimes I also see changes in the authors name. You can see 'j. doe' turned into 'J. Doe', for instance. This suggests that Windows opened it in the background and wrote the last user who did so in it, which could have been spelled differently on a previous computer, or whatever.

In this case it's a Debian 7 server with Samba 3.6.6-6+deb7u5, and a PC with Windows 7 64 bit, but I've seen it on other configurations as well.

Can anybody shed any light on this?